# How to get the complete list of the Locators (targets) available for each Command in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

Does anyone know where the complete list of the Locators (targets) available for each Command in Selenium IDE can be found? 
For instance, if I select 'click' command, which locators can be applied to this command (id, name, link etc.)?
Have been trying to find this information in the official documentation for a while but no result.